# What does x86-64 linux kernel do when it needs to run x86-32 program?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Since x86-64 CPU can run x86-32 code directly, and write to `eax` will zeros out the higher bits of `rax`, so the syscall number will be right. What other job does the kernel have to do to run x86-32 program?

Comment: It puts the CPU into compat mode, by clearing the `L` bit in a segment descriptor in the GDT, and using an `iret` to set `cs:rip` to a 32-bit code segment while jumping to user-space.  Of course it needs some special options for some system calls like `mmap` to make sure allocated memory is within the low 32 bits of virtual address space, and ABI differences for structs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What other job does the kernel have to do to run x86-32 program?

All 64-bit parameters need to be split (e.g. passed in `edx:eax` instead of just `rax`). The mechanism used to call the kernel API is completely different (`int 0x80` vs. `syscall`). The stack layout (which matters for things like sending signals back to user-space signal handlers) is different. Virtual memory management has to be aware that user-space can't use 64-bit pointers. Different segment registers are used for TLS (`gs` for 32-bit, `fs` for 64-bit).

Mostly it's different enough that that you end up with completely separate system call entry/exit and dispatch code (where both interfaces call the same internal functions after parameters and calling conventions are handled).

Comment: Indeed.  Some entries in `ia32_sys_call_table[]` are the native 64-bit system call functions that are also in the native system-call dispatch table, but many are wrapper functions that handle stuff like [`sys_llseek(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/llseek.2.html) taking separate `unsigned long offset_high` and `unsigned long offset_low` args, or that account for struct-layout differences.   (Actually, `sys_llseek` only only exists for 32-bit; For 64-bit `lseek`'s single arg is wide enough.).

Comment: See [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code) for a tour of the Linux kernel entry points into an x86-64 kernel from 32-bit user-space (or from 64-bit user-space using the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI; it always returns to user-space via `iret`, restoring the 32-bit or 64-bit code segment that user-space was running from).